# PHP sessions not working for game

Tags: php, session

I am trying to imitate a game called SKUNK (you play it with dice) for an assignment.

I can't get the sessions to work. This is my first time using PHP. Also I was told it can be done without sessions.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="get" action= "skunk.php">
    <h1>PLAY SKUNK</h1>

    ROLL AGAIN? <br> 
    yes<input type="radio" name="role2" value="yes"/>
    no<input type="radio" name="role2" value="no"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit"/>

    </form>

<?php 

session_start();
    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
    $_SESSION["u"] = array(0);
    $_SESSION["n"] = array(0);
    $_SESSION["k2"] = array(0);
    $rand = 0;
    $rand2 = 0;
    $_SESSION["round"] = 1;
    if($_REQUEST["role2"] == "yes"){
        $rand = rand (1, 6);
        $rand2 = rand(1, 6);
         if($rand == 1 and $rand ==1){
            switch ($_SESSION["round"]) {
                case 1:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
                    $_SESSION["u"] = array(0);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
                    $_SESSION["u"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["n"] = array(0);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
                    $_SESSION["u"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["n"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k2"] = array(0); 
                    break;
            }
         }
         if($rand > 1 and $rand2 > 1) {
            switch ($_SESSION["round"]) {
                case 1:
                    array_push($_SESSION["s"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    array_push($_SESSION["k1"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    array_push($_SESSION["u"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    array_push($_SESSION["n"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    array_push($_SESSION["k2"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
            }
            $_SESSION["round"]++;
        }

        if($_SESSION["round"] > 5){
            session_destroy();
        }
        echo "you rolled: " . $rand . "\n";
        echo "you rolled: " . $rand2;

    }

?>
    <table style="width:100%" border="1" >
          <tr>
            <td>S</td>
            <td>K</td> 
            <td>U</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>K</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%" border="1" >
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["s"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["k1"]); ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["u"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["n"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["k2"]); ?></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: session_start(); must be the very first line of your code, after <?php. Try putting session_start(); in the very beginning of the file.

Comment: still not working I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: the problem may be at some other place, because I run your code by changing the place of session_start(); as mentioned above and all sessions are set.

Comment: you can try printing session array as echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: okay thanks... ill try that out. I just expected to see the totals incrementing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use session at any point session_start() should be the first line of just before any printing functions.

start session at the starting of the page then try to print echo " $_SESSION["s"]";